# Какой есть хороший способ создать кривую между двумя градиентами div в CSS?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, анимация

У меня есть два `div` с отдельным градиентным фоном, и мне нужно создать кривую `S-Shape` между ними.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот пример скрипта для градиентных div: https://jsfiddle.net/JerryGoyal/rjyfc46c/2/

```
<div id="section1">

</div>
<div id="section2">

</div>
#section1{
  height:200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #ad3, #add);
}
#section2{
  height:200px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #de350b, #0065ff);
}
```

Есть несколько вещей, которые пришли мне в голову, но:

- **svg**: не знаю, как обращаться с другим градиентом div.
- **border-radius**: не удалось получить истинную S-подобную кривую, и она становится уродливой, когда я изменяю размер экрана.
- **clip-path**: не поддерживается некоторыми браузерами https://caniuse.com/css-clip-path
- **png image**: нет! должен быть динамический контент.

P.S: необходимо прочитать для будущего решения https://css-tricks.com/creating-non-rectangular-headers/

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/49669689/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Здесь решение с использованием [`linearGradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Gradients) `SVG`

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background:linear-gradient(to bottom right, #de350b, #0065ff);
}
svg {
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg mlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox="0 0 64 64">
    <defs>
    <linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ad3" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#add" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
    <path d='M0 10 C30 28 38 0 64 10 L64 0 L0 0 Z'  fill="url(#grad)"/>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Здесь также полезный [онлайн-инструмент](http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M0%2010%20C30%2028%2038%200%2064%2010%20L64%200%20L0%200%20Z) для легкого редактирования фигуры (просто добавьте путь к URL-адресу для редактирования `http://jxnblk.com/paths/?d=M0 10 C30 28 38 0 64 10 L64 0 L0 0 Z` )

Другая идея, с тем же SVG, который используется в качестве фона, поэтому вы можете легко обрабатывать контент над ним:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 64 64" width="500" ><defs><linearGradient id="grad" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="100%"><stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ad3" /><stop offset="100%" stop-color="#add" /></linearGradient></defs><path d="M0 10 C30 28 38 0 64 10 L64 0 L0 0 Z"  fill="url(#grad)"/></svg>'), 
  linear-gradient(to bottom right, #de350b, #0065ff);
  
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
  align-items:center;
  flex-direction:column;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<p>TOP</p>
<p>BOTTOM</p>
</div>
```